Transform JSON to JOLT Expression
Input JSON
[
      {
        "zone_name": "01 green",
        "zone_type_name": "Green",
        "conditions": {
          "timestamp": "2024-05-15 10:23:52",
          "num_samples": 12,
          "img_extent": {
            "min_lng": -5.877219,
            "max_lng": -5.876672,
            "min_lat": 54.220024,
            "max_lat": 54.220338
          },
          "moisture_avg": 33.97,
          "moisture_img": "https://api.pogoturfpro.com/api/partner/maya/insight/5278277?attribute=M&key=05127be738e28884c2eba2585968eb687aa0cd20dadc299f5282ff6bf82f5e5b",
          "moisture_avg_color": "#4EC3DA",
          "moisture_avg_rating": "High",
          "ec_avg": 0.2,
          "ec_img": "https://api.pogoturfpro.com/api/partner/maya/insight/5278277?attribute=E&key=05127be738e28884c2eba2585968eb687aa0cd20dadc299f5282ff6bf82f5e5b",
          "ec_avg_color": "#C2AE96",
          "ec_avg_rating": "Low",
          "salinity_index_avg": 0.59,
          "salinity_index_img": "https://api.pogoturfpro.com/api/partner/maya/insight/5278277?attribute=S&key=05127be738e28884c2eba2585968eb687aa0cd20dadc299f5282ff6bf82f5e5b",
          "salinity_index_avg_color": "#AF4440",
          "salinity_index_avg_rating": "Critically Low",
          "surface_heat_f_avg": 66.13,
          "surface_heat_f_img": "https://api.pogoturfpro.com/api/partner/maya/insight/5278277?attribute=T&key=05127be738e28884c2eba2585968eb687aa0cd20dadc299f5282ff6bf82f5e5b",
          "surface_heat_f_avg_color": "#2D882D",
          "surface_heat_f_avg_rating": "Optimal",
          "soil_temp_f_avg": 62.72,
          "soil_temp_f_img": "https://api.pogoturfpro.com/api/partner/maya/insight/5278277?attribute=ST&key=05127be738e28884c2eba2585968eb687aa0cd20dadc299f5282ff6bf82f5e5b",
          "soil_temp_f_avg_color": "#C2AE96",
          "soil_temp_f_avg_rating": "Low",
          "notes": []
        },
        "pins": []
      }
]

Expected Output JSON
{
  "Time" : "2024-05-15 10:23:52",
  "VMC" : 33.97,
  "EC" : 0.2,
  "Temp_Soil_F" : 62.72,
  "Temp_Soil" : 34.844,
  "Latitude" : 54.220181,
  "Longitude" : -5.876945,
  "idgroup" : "group(7750ceae-0528-44cb-9aeb-8865602d7f6f)",
  "iduser" : "user(84ca8fa3-199f-4a3e-9c86-699edce12846)",
  "Rod_Length" : "S",
  "Soil_type" : "D",
  "VWC_Mode" : "V"
}

I have the JOLT created, I only need to remove the square brackets on the outside. All the calculations needed are already in the below JOLT.
idgroup, iduser, Rod_Length, Soil_type & VWC_Mode are hardcoded values
Time is timestamp
VWC is moisture_avg
EC is ec_avg Temp_Soil_F is soil_temp_f_avg
Temp_Soil is celcius(soil_temp_f_avg) - convert soil_temp_f_avg to celsius
Latitude is (min_lat+ max_lat) / 2
Longitude is (min_lng + max_lng) /
Current JOLT
[
      {
        "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
        "spec": {
          "new_attr_idgroup": "group(7750ceae-0528-44cb-9aeb-8865602d7f6f)",
          "new_attr_iduser": "user(84ca8fa3-199f-4a3e-9c86-699edce12846)",
          "conditions": {
            "new_attr_Time": "=(@(1,timestamp))",
            "new_attr_VMC": "=(@(1,moisture_avg))",
            "new_attr_EC": "=(@(1,ec_avg))",
            "new_attr_Temp_Soil_F": "=(@(1,soil_temp_f_avg))",
            "Temp_Cel": "=doubleSum(@(1,soil_temp_f_avg),-32)",
            "new_attr_Temp_Soil": "=divideAndRound(3,@(1,soil_temp_f_avg),1.8)",
            "nnew_attr_Latitude": "=doubleSum(@(1,img_extent.min_lat),@(1,img_extent.max_lat))",
            "new_attr_Latitude": "=divideAndRound(6,@(1,nnew_attr_Latitude),2)",
            "nnew_attr_Longitude": "=doubleSum(@(1,img_extent.min_lng),@(1,img_extent.max_lng))",
            "new_attr_Longitude": "=divideAndRound(6,@(1,nnew_attr_Longitude),2)"
          },
          "new_attr_Rod_Length": "S",
          "new_attr_Soil_type": "D",
          "new_attr_VWC_Mode": "V"
        }
      },
      {
        "operation": "shift",
        "spec": {
          "new_attr_*": "&(0,1)",
          "conditions": {
            "new_attr_*": "&(0,1)"
          }
        }
      }
]


Hi Bhadraka, the current Jolt Spec returns null as result

yes, I need to modify the current jolt to get my expected output JSON I have put. this is the same as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78505945/transform-a-json-using-jolt-expression. only the input JSON is bit different

I only need to remove the square brackets on the outside : What square brackets are you metioning about ? Can you add the expected output as well please ( Btw, the current output is not the one shared within the question )

Don't remove the square brackets just call the first item eg. JSON[0] or JOLT[0]

I have updated the question with Input and Output JSON. please create the JOLT with given specifications in the question

please paste this current input and spec and toggle Transform button on https://jolt-demo.appspot.com/#inception and tell me what you get

I get a null, what I need is modify my current JOLT to get the output JSON.
If you can write the JOLT expression to get the output using input JSON that would be helpful.
idgroup, iduser, Rod_Length, Soil_type & VWC_Mode are hardcoded values
Time is timestamp VWC is moisture_avg EC is ec_avg Temp_Soil_F is soil_temp_f_avg Temp_Soil is celcius(soil_temp_f_avg) - convert soil_temp_f_avg to celsius
Latitude is (min_lat+ max_lat) / 2 Longitude is (min_lng + max_lng) /

OK, that's the problem, the current output is already is not the one comes after Output JSON, but do you mean that Output JSON is expected output ?

yes, Output JSON is expected output. I need the current JOLT modified to get the Output JSON

You could add nohing but one more nesting layer, which starts with "*": { and ends of course with an extra } , for each spec
